# Как динамический сгенирировать анимацию в гриде WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть информация с БД. Информация может дополняется. Согласно количеству информации, Ниже я привел пример, как это должно выглядеть:

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

В каждой странице показано по 2 элемента. Когда мы нажимаем на кнопки "след" и "пред" должно произойти анимация, и будет показано следующие 2 порций информаций.

Я должен сгенерировать это динамический. Есть варианты?

Comment: А откуда взялось требование, что анимация должна генерироваться динамически? Выглядеть будет одинаково в любом случае.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы все же сделал все с помощью `ListBox` с `WrapPanel` в качестве панели. И включил у него постраничный скролл. Примерно так:

```
<ListBox x:Name="DataList">        
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

А по кнопке просто выбирал нужный элемент и вызывал `ScrollIntoView`

```
DataList.ScrollIntoView(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что надо генерировать динамически. Но если я правильно уловил суть вопроса, то мое решение это иметь вторую копию сверстанного экрана, по нажатию любой кнопки заполнять нужными данными и размещать за пределами видимости справа или слева соотв. После подготовки данных делать параллельную анимацию этих 2х "экранов".

Comment: А это не будет занимать время? Все таки данные будут из БД вытаскиваться.